# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partit

Tags: php, mysql, version, row-number

query that is throwing error is ...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by chiti order by rcvddate desc) from received LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

> select *, row_number() over(partition by chiti order by rcvddate desc) from received

before i was working with localhost mysql and in localhost this query used to worked
and now when i shifted my code to online hostgator server this query is throwing error near >> over(partition by chiti order by rcvddate desc) as rn from received )a LEFT JOIN chiti b on a.chiti=b.id LEFT JOIN customers c on a.customer=c.id LEFT JOIN

my hostgator php version --     **PHP 8.1 (ea-php81)**

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.33

i even added image of structure of my table received

Please help me my work has been stopped because of this error

Answer (score 1):

You might to check not the PHP version but MySQL. MySQL introduced the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in version 8.0.

Comment: i added mysql version  tooo

Comment: "mysqlnd 7.4.33" is a PHP extension. you need to check your MySql version - it is different. You can do it by executing the query "SELECT VERSION();" or in the CPanel.